# PHP Error: "Call to undefined function AddUser() ". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

Code: http://pastebin.com/h8WuYbJn
Full error:
 **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function AddUser() in **C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\steam.php** on line **37**

What exactly am I doing wrong? Everything *should* be right, but it isn't (at least according to PHP).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$x->AddUser` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use the `.` in PHP. Use `->` instead, eg:

```
$x->AddUser('FakeId','FakeUser');
$x->Refresh('FakeUser');
```

The `.` is PHP's concatenation operator, so it thinks you want

```
$x . AddUser('FakeId', 'FakeUser'); // $x concatenated with AddUser(...)
```

And of course `Adduser()` is undefined.

Comment: That's what I get for using Python all day. Thanks. :D